# SQLDeveloper support IN condition for bind variable

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using the latest SQLDeveloper version from Oracle and I have a basic query that I've pasted into a SQL Worksheet.

The query contains an IN condition and is associated with a bind variable

```
select * from items where item in :itemId
```

When I select "Run Statement" I am prompted to Enter Binds, but for the life of me I have not been able to enter the proper format with multiple values to allow the query to run properly and return the results I want.

Any ideas, is this supported ?

Comment: It's been years since I've been working with Oracle, so I'm guessing a bit, but I'd say you can't. Because ```:itemId``` is a parameter and you can't parameterize (if that's a word;) the ```WHERE IN``` with multiple values.

Comment: The values that will be catch when you are prompted for values will be string. For example, you entered `Sea, Earth, Sky`, oracle will treat it as one string, so it will read it like this `'Sea,Earth,Sky'` which is not the appropriate format for IN clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but there's a 'trick'

```
SELECT owner,
       object_name,
       object_type
  FROM all_objects
 WHERE object_name LIKE :SEARCH
   AND owner NOT IN (
    'SYS',
    'MDSYS',
    'DBSNMP',
    'SYSTEM',
    'DVSYS',
    'APEX_050100',
    'PUBLIC',
    'ORDS_METADATA',
    'APEX_LISTENER'
)
   AND object_type IN (
    SELECT regexp_substr(:bind_ename_comma_sep_list,'[^,]+',1,level)
      FROM dual CONNECT BY
        regexp_substr(:bind_ename_comma_sep_list,'[^,]+',1,level) IS NOT NULL
)
 ORDER BY owner,
          object_name,
          object_type;
```

The trick is explained [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/aramamoo/passing-comma-separated-string-as-bind-variable-for-vo-querys-in-operator-v2).